# How to get rendered height of stackpanel without actually displaying it (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have implemented a custom AccordionControl. 
It alternatingly consists of a HeaderView followed by a StackLayout.

When a HeaderView is tapped the corresponding StackLayout is expanded using an animation.

For the animation I need a start point and an end point (the rendered height). I have currently implemented a workaround, which shortly displays the StackLayout, gets the rendered height and then animates it. (The result obviously is a not so smooth animation)

**Animation-workaround**

```
stackLayout.IsVisible = true;
double heightWhenRendered = stackLayout.Height;

var animation = new Animation(d => stackLayout.HeightRequest = d, start: 0, end: heightWhenRendered, easing: Easing.CubicInOut);
this._runningAnimations.Add(animation);
animation.Commit(stackLayout, "Expand", finished: (x,s) =>
{
   this._runningAnimations.Remove(animation);
});
```

Comment: What are the contents of the stack? It might be easier to calculate content height if they're just labels or something

Comment: Unfortunately they are not just labelsbut you can bind any DataTemplate to it

Comment: instead of creating a new animation, try using LayoutTo :
`double heightWhenRendered = stackLayout.Height;`
`Rectangle startRect = new Rectangle(xLocation, yLocation, stackLayout.Width, 0);`
`stackLayout.LayoutTo(startRect, 0, null);`
`stackLayout.IsVisible = true;`
`Rectangle endRect = new Rectangle(xLocation, yLocation, stackLayout.Width, heightWhenRendered);`
`stackLayout.LayoutTo(endRect, AnimationTime, Easing.CubicInOut`

Comment: I actually really wanted to use that because of the async convenience. But I camr to think that LayoutTo just moves my view and doesn't scale it? What would be the xlocation and ylocstion in your example? I feel like this does not solve my original problem. Am I right or did I miss somrthing here?

Comment: xLocation and yLocation would be the top left corner of where you want the stacklayout to be

Comment: As for the rest, I'm not really sure. This is how I do all my animations, but there may be better ways

Comment: I have now tried your approach and it isn't working.
The StackLayout isn't being animated but instead instantly jumps to the endRect bounds.

Comment: mark the function async and put Await in front of the second LayoutTo

Comment: I can't believe I made thid mistake but I just realised that I have not actually set the height of the stacklayout to 0 before animating it. What difference do I hsve to exprct when I execute thr animation inside an async method with await vs when I do it without?

Comment: When I do use it with async methods I get an UnhandledException (maybe because I don't use a Dispatcher?).

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/async_support_overview/
Await forces your method to wait for the animation to complete before continuing. If you do anything that causes a redraw while your LayoutTo is still animating, the animation will immediately complete. Using await is usually my solution for "a later animation is starting before this one finished" related problems. If it works without await then I'd stick with that. I don't know what's causing that exception though.